# How to make a many2many field sortable in odoo 9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a many2many field , but I'm unable to sort it . Can anyone help?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you share your efforts in your question.

Comment: I did nothing so far

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to sort a `many2many` field if it is `many2many_tags` or any display widget other than the default [`many2many` widget](http://ludwiktrammer.github.io/odoo/form-widgets-many2many-fields-options-odoo.html#many2many-widget-default).

With that default `many2many` widget, it should display like a list in the form. You *may* be able to define the tree view and set a [`default_order`](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/views.html#lists) attribute. Something like this:

```
<field name="your_m2m_field">
    <tree default_order="sub_field1, sub_field2 desc">
        <field name="sub_field1/>
        <field name="sub_field2/>
        <field name="sub_field3/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: Yeah @travisw it seems impossible . I did alot of searching but no solution.